# Using Firefox-addon to click a element who has onclick="return:false;"

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, firefox-addon

I try to make some **Firefox add-on** for one website.

But that website has a HTML & jQuery like this...

**HTML+jQUery:** (onPage)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('a').on('click',function(){alert('Yo!');});
    });
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">SomeEvent</a>
```

This I cant use `$('a').click();` *(My add-one is jQuery included)*

How can I tell my Firefox add-on to **click this** ? or clone onClick event ?

I have no idea how to do. *Or I just code in Greasemonkey or iMarco only*

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really give any details as to your existing code, and whether you use XUL, the add-on SDK (`page-mod`?) or whatever.

But in general you can just [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click), e.g.

```
document.querySelector("a").click();
```

(You'll need to use the correct content `document`. What is correct depends on what toolkit you're using)